# Who can help me understand MSDN publishing system?

Tags: msdn

I'm suddenly interested in the MSDN library's architecture from the perspective of accessing its content, including version control (like MSDN ASP.NET 4.0/ASP.NET 3.5/ASP.NET2.0/ASP.NET 1.0).

But I cannot find any articles and posts that talk about it.

Has anyone ever investigated this, and can you kindly share with me?

Thanks in advance.

Elaine

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I don't understand what you are asking

Comment: @Daniel, I'm asking who knows MSDN library's resolution on the localization, content version control. I know it isn't look like a questions, more looks like a discussion... Maybe I need to edit it to be more question-oriented...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood correctly what you are looking for, but here is an article:

[Consuming MSDN Web Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163541.aspx)

Comment: appreciate you much! That's what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the start of the [MSDN's take on globalization and localization from the WPF perspective](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753931.aspx).

It has a *Versions* link at the top that allows you to view information for the specific .NET Framework that you're using. And in the left-hand pane you can choose specific aspects in which you might be interested.

But I'm not clear on exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks, It's helpful. But what I mean is MSDN Library it self's localization/globalization resolution..